# Is there an optimized method for finding the farthest corner of a cube in 3D

Tags: algorithm, geometry

If a have a cube **C** with 8 corners ( not axis aligned ) and a random point **P** can I do better than just checking all the corners and picking the corner with the greatest distance from *P* or is it possible to reduce the number of checks by taking into account the symmetrical nature of the cube?

Comment: You can represent vector C0P in orthogonal basis C0C1, C0C2,C0C3, but I suspect that simple calculation of squared distances might be faster.

Answer (score 4):

1. Transform the point `P` to the cube's *principle basis*, i.e. in which it is axially aligned (call the new point `Q`), and the origin is the centre of the cube in world space
2. To find the furthest point in this frame, `F`: using the X-axis as an example, if

   - `Q.x > 0` then `F.x = -L`, where `L` is the side length of the cube
   - `Q.x < 0` then `F.x = L`
   - `Q.x == 0` (strictly `abs(Q.x) < EPSILON`), then `F.x = 0`
3. Do step 2 for the other two axes as well
4. Transform the resulting point `F` *back* to world space, by the inverse transform of the one performed in step 1. This will give the furthest point on the cube that you want.

---

EDIT: let's see why this could be more efficient.

- Original method: 8 X square distance calculations = 8 X (3 floating point multiplications + 2 additions)
- New method: 2 matrix multiplications = 2 X (9 fp multiplications + 6 additions)

As you can see, the new method uses fewer multiplications and additions.

Comment: It's a good idea ( +1 pt from me ) but I think I can dodge the transformation back to the basis by just projecting the point onto the untransformed axis via dot products and making basically the same observations you have pointed out.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing 1) You got it the wrong way round - the inverse transformation is multiplying the basis vectors by the components, and the *forward* transformation is the dot product stuff; 2) that is *exactly* equivalent to the "transformation" i was referring to - i.e. multiplication by a matrix

Comment: @spug: there is no need to perform the reverse transformation, the original corners are already known.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I took advantage of that in my fully coded solution posted above. In the end I have 1 matrix multiplication (3 dot products), 3 divisions and 3 boolean tests. I can also be able to throw/cache the divisions.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: why on Earth do you use divisions ? They are very costly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I switched the divisions for multiplications by 0.5 and it made _zero_ difference to the performance of the algorithm. If you check the code then you will see I am dividing by a constant __2__ and it is likely that the compiler will optimize this. If it was division by a variable then perhaps the results would be different.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: you can probably avoid this operation by premultiplying the coefficients.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much difference overall. I tried it

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: it saves three multiplies.

Comment: Yes I know :) But when I profile the code it makes no measurable difference. I would have to understand the output of the C# compiler to see why this is so.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: it is possible that multiplies by a power of 2 are done in a special way.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the coordinates of the random point to a local coordinate system aligned with the cube. This takes 9 multiplies and 9 adds.

If the local system is centered on the cube, three sign tests will tell you the furthest corner.

---

A good understanding of the problem is obtained by the *locus* approach.

If you consider all positions of the random point that lead to the same answer (i.e. same corner index; this is the furthest Voronoi diagram of the vertices), you partition space in the eight octants defined by three bisecting planes of the cube. Telling a point among eight regions requires three binary tests (`Lg(8)`). The tests in question tell on which side of the planes the point lies, and this requires the evaluation of affine expressions `aX+bY+cZ+d`.

In the "algebraic decision tree" model, this is probably optimal.

---

**Update**:

As only the signs matter, you can normalize the coefficients so that one of them is unit, and spare a multiply (`aX+bY+cZ+d>0 -> X+b'Y+c'Z+d>0'`). You can also trade an addition for a comparison (`X+bY+cZ+d>0 -> X+bY+cZ>d'`). Hence, 6 multiplies, 6 adds and 3 comparisons in total.

[For numerical stability, one should divide by the largest coefficient. This unfortunately causes the expressions to depend on which it is. This can be circumvented by writing twenty seven (!) index computation functions - see below - and invoking the right one by pointer.]

---

Assuming that the coefficients have been precomputed, the following expression gives the corner index, in range `[0,7]`:

```
(X + b*Y + c*Z > d) + ((X + b'*Y + c'*Z > d') << 1) + ((X + b"*Y + c"*Z > d") << 2)
```

With some luck, the compiler can compute it in a branchless way by means of conditional assignments, requiring like 15 flops and 5 ops.

Comment: I realized that your solution is identical to mine except for the trick of pre-multiplication of the axis vectors to reduce the dot products from three multiplications to two. +1 pt

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: and I am not returning vertex coordinates but just an index.

Comment: Using an indexed lookup might be faster than the 3 conditionals I use. I will profile it and try it.

Comment: In c# there is a small __gotcha__. You can't bit shift a boolean. You have to use the conditional operator and thus you end up with 3 branches to generate the indexes. It is possible to use ``unsafe`` to cast to bool to int and avoid the branch. However it is possible that if the CLR changes the implementation of bool ( unlikely ) then the code will break by just marshaling the internal bit representation of bool into an int.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: it is worth to try the conditional operator (and no need to shift), as the compiler might translate to a conditional assignment anyway. The "offical" cast is `Convert.ToInt32`. There is also a `Sign` function, but I wouldn't expect it to be efficient :(

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 just expands to a ternery operator ``!value?0:1``

Answer (score 0):

The farthest corner satisfies that at least one "delta" of `|xc-xp|` or `|yc-yp|`or `|zc-zp|` is maximum.

Test each "delta", storing the "candidates". A corner is "candidate" if its delta is greater or equal to the same delta for another candidate.

If a previous candidate is defeated in its "maximum condition", delete it from the list of candidates. For example, if corner 4 became candidate because its delta-y was the maximum but now corner 6 has a greater delta-y (the other deltas were not reason for corner 4) then corner 4 can not longer be candidate.

The first tested corner has the three maximum, so it needs to be defeated three times (on x, y and z) to get out of the list of candidates.

Note that the test to become a candidate is `d1>=d2` not just `d1>d2`

Now test distances (squared distances is enough) only for the candidates.

Note that all corners can be at the same distance from point if it lies in center of the cube. The solution can be not only one corner, but two, four or eight.

Answer (score 0):

@spug triggered my realization that I already had most of the code I needed.

I had previously developed an optimal way of solving the **closest point** ( not necessarily a corner) on a cube. That code required only minor modifications to return the closest **corner** on the cube. Logically the furthest away point on a cube is the opposite corner to the closest corner.

The principle is to project the point onto the three principle axis and test how far along each axis the projection is. If it is greater than half way then set the index of that axis to false otherwise set it to true. After doing this for three axis you have three boolean variables you can use to pick the corner.

After profiling over 10 million random points the following data is available.

Naive Linear Search Algorithm - 643ms
Fast Algorithm                - 481ms

The C# code I ended up using was

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Vector3 FurthestPointFromFast(Vector3 q)
    {
        //BasisVectors( TransformMatrix, out var vx, out var vy, out var vz );
        var origin = BoxCorners.V000;

        // Get the pre-calculated principle
        // axes of the box with origin at V000
        Vector3 vx = BoxCorners.Px;
        Vector3 vy = BoxCorners.Py;
        Vector3 vz = BoxCorners.Pz;

        // Get the pre-calculated prinicple
        // axes lengths squared of the box at V000
        double lx = BoxCorners.Lx2;
        double ly = BoxCorners.Ly2;
        double lz = BoxCorners.Lz2;

        var d = q - origin;
        double tx = Vector3.Dot( d, vx );
        double ty = Vector3.Dot( d, vy );
        double tz = Vector3.Dot( d, vz );

        bool ix = tx < lx / 2;
        bool iy = ty < ly / 2;
        bool iz = tz < lz / 2;

        return ix
            ? (iy
                ? (iz
                    ? BoxCorners.V111
                    : BoxCorners.V110)
                : (iz
                    ? BoxCorners.V101
                    : BoxCorners.V100))
            : (iy
                ? (iz
                    ? BoxCorners.V011
                    : BoxCorners.V010)
                : (iz
                    ? BoxCorners.V001
                    : BoxCorners.V000));
    }
```

where an instance of BoxCorners is from the following class. It is assumed that a box is relatively static compared to the number of checks made against it so calculated values such as the side lengths of the box are stored along with the coordinates of each corner.

```
public class BoxCorners
{
    public Vector3 V111;
    public Vector3 V110;
    public Vector3 V101;
    public Vector3 V100;
    public Vector3 V011;
    public Vector3 V010;
    public Vector3 V001;
    public Vector3 V000;

    // These are the vectors starting at the box origin (V000)
    // They are precalculated and usefull in other algorithms
    #region Principle Axis
    public Vector3 Origin; 
    public Vector3 Px;
    public Vector3 Py;
    public Vector3 Pz;
    /// <summary>
    /// Px length squared
    /// </summary>
    public double Lx2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Py length squared
    /// </summary>
    public double Ly2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Pz length squared
    /// </summary>
    public double Lz2;
    #endregion


    public BoxCorners(Vector3 v000, Vector3 v001, Vector3 v010, Vector3 v011, Vector3 v100, Vector3 v101, Vector3 v110, Vector3 v111)
    {
        V000 = v000;
        V001 = v001;
        V010 = v010;
        V011 = v011;
        V100 = v100;
        V101 = v101;
        V110 = v110;
        V111 = v111;

        Origin = V000;

        Px = (V100 - Origin);
        Py = (V010 - Origin);
        Pz = (V001 - Origin);

        Lx2 = Px.LengthSquared();
        Ly2 = Py.LengthSquared();
        Lz2 = Py.LengthSquared();
    }

}
```

The original naive algorith is below

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    void Acc(ref Vector3 v, ref Vector3 q, ref double max, ref Vector3 maxV)
    {
        var m = Vector3.DistanceSquared(v, q);
        if (!(m > max))
            return;
        max = m;
        maxV = v;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the furthest point on the box from the point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="q"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Vector3 FurthestPointFrom(Vector3 q)
    {

        var max = 0.0;
        var bc = BoxCorners;
        var r = Vector3.Zero;

        Acc(ref bc.V111, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V110, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V101, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V100, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V011, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V010, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V001, ref q, ref max, ref r);
        Acc(ref bc.V000, ref q, ref max, ref r);

        return r;
    }
```

The [double numerics nuget](https://github.com/Weingartner/System.Numerics.DoubleVectors) package is used for 3D vector primitives.